# Netty-3.5.3-Final : ChannelBuffer doesn't handle bytearray like 3.4.5-Final does

Tags: arrays, netty

I have a major issue with Netty-3.5.3-Final that made me revert to netty-3.4.5-final. It looks like that Bytearray sent in the ChannelBuffer are ok but Bytearray read from a ChannelBuffer are no longer what they used to be. I tested my exact same code with the two different netty versions (3.4.5 vs 3.5.3). My test case use two Netty HTTP server (one contacting the other) and share the same netty version. I can reproduce my bug either on localhost or on a local-network server.

Have you modified the first bytes of the header?

Here's my Excel binary output (sorry, there's no way to attach a file) As you can see, I output my bytearray, deflate it, output it again, receive it on my server, inflate it and output it. With netty 3-4-5 final I have the same result (which is correct). With netty 3-5-3 I have a massive amount of bytes and zLib is unable to understand the header. If I swap out my Netty lib, the whole thing starts to work again.

> Login : netty-3.4.5.Final.jar :: UNCOMPRESSED
>
> 0 0 9 3 1 10 3 -127 15 99 111 109 46 102 114 105 109 97 115 116 117
>   100 105 111 46 115 110 111 119 115 116 111 114 109 46 97 117 116 104
>   101 110 116 105 99 97 116 105 111 110 46 99 111 114 101 46 108 111 103
>   105 110 46 97 109 102 46 71 101 116 84 111 107 101 110 82 101 113 117
>   101 115 116
>
> VALUE VALUE " " " " VALUE c o m . f r i m a s t u d i o . s n o w s t
>   o r m . a u t h e n t i c a t i o n . c o r e . l o g i n . a m f . G
>   e t T o k e n R e q u e s t
>
> COMPRESSED IN DEFLATE FUNCTION
>
> 120 1 5 -63 49 14 -128 48 8 0 -64 -102 78 -70 -8 19 -66 -31 110 -4 0
>   -87 84 -119 2 -79 -48 56 -5 115 -17 82 26 -13 48 -27 111 46 38 80 27 11 122 -12 -99 13 92 -19 -11 -80 38 -128 61 78 -46 -32 -126 -63 -90 80
>   -84 17 -36 118 -80 2 74 -123 -123 98 -77 -117 116 -91 -89 -109 -57 15 41 73 28 -81
>
> RECEIVED IN INFLATE FUNCTION
>
> 120 1 5 -63 49 14 -128 48 8 0 -64 -102 78 -70 -8 19 -66 -31 110 -4 0
>   -87 84 -119 2 -79 -48 56 -5 115 -17 82 26 -13 48 -27 111 46 38 80 27 11 122 -12 -99 13 92 -19 -11 -80 38 -128 61 78 -46 -32 -126 -63 -90 80
>   -84 17 -36 118 -80 2 74 -123 -123 98 -77 -117 116 -91 -89 -109 -57 15 41 73 28 -81
>
> UNCOMPRESSED IN INFLATE FUNCTION
>
> 0 0 9 3 1 10 3 -127 15 99 111 109 46 102 114 105 109 97 115 116 117
>   100 105 111 46 115 110 111 119 115 116 111 114 109 46 97 117 116 104
>   101 110 116 105 99 97 116 105 111 110 46 99 111 114 101 46 108 111 103
>   105 110 46 97 109 102 46 71 101 116 84 111 107 101 110 82 101 113 117
>   101 115 116
>
> VALUE VALUE " " " " VALUE c o m . f r i m a s t u d i o . s n o w s t
>   o r m . a u t h e n t i c a t i o n . c o r e . l o g i n . a m f . G
>   e t T o k e n R e q u e s t
>
> Login : netty-3.5.3.Final.jar :: UNCOMPRESSED
>
> 0 0 9 3 1 10 3 -127 15 99 111 109 46 102 114 105 109 97 115 116 117
>   100 105 111 46 115 110 111 119 115 116 111 114 109 46 97 117 116 104
>   101 110 116 105 99 97 116 105 111 110 46 99 111 114 101 46 108 111 103
>   105 110 46 97 109 102 46 71 101 116 84 111 107 101 110 82 101 113 117
>   101 115 116
>
> VALUE VALUE " " " " VALUE c o m . f r i m a s t u d i o . s n o w s t
>   o r m . a u t h e n t i c a t i o n . c o r e . l o g i n . a m f . G
>   e t T o k e n R e q u e s t
>
> COMPRESSED IN DEFLATE FUNCTION
>
> 120 1 5 -63 49 14 -128 48 8 0 -64 -102 78 -70 -8 19 -66 -31 110 -4 0
>   -87 84 -119 2 -79 -48 56 -5 115 -17 82 26 -13 48 -27 111 46 38 80 27 11 122 -12 -99 13 92 -19 -11 -80 38 -128 61 78 -46 -32 -126 -63 -90 80
>   -84 17 -36 118 -80 2 74 -123 -123 98 -77 -117 116 -91 -89 -109 -57 15 41 73 28 -81
>
> RECEIVED IN INFLATE FUNCTION
>
> 72 84 84 80 47 49 46 49 32 50 48 48 32 79 75 13 10 67 111 110 110 101
>   99 116 105 111 110 58 32 107 101 101 112 45 97 108 105 118 101 13 10
>   67 111 110 116 101 110 116 45 84 121 112 101 58 32 97 112 112 108 105
>   99 97 116 105 111 110 47 111 99 116 101 116 45 115 116 114 101 97 109
>   13 10 67 111 110 116 101 110 116 45 76 101 110 103 116 104 58 32 49 51
>   48 13 10 69 120 112 105 114 101 115 58 32 84 104 117 32 65 117 103 32
>   48 50 32 48 57 58 48 55 58 53 52 32 69 68 84 32 50 48 49 50 13 10 68
>   97 116 101 58 32 84 104 117 32 65 117 103 32 48 50 32 48 57 58 48 55
>   58 53 52 32 69 68 84 32 50 48 49 50 13 10 67 97 99 104 101 45 67 111
>   110 116 114 111 108 58 32 109 97 120 45 97 103 101 61 49 13 10 13 10
>   120 1 -29 100 102 -28 50 110 20 76 -50 -49 -43 75 43 -54 -52 77 44 46
>   41 77 -55 -52 -41 43 -50 -53 47 47 46 -55 47 -54 -43 75 44 45 -55 72
>   -51 43 -55 76 78 44 -55 -52 -49 -45 75 -50 47 74 -43 -53 -55 79 -49 -52 -45 75 -52 77 -45 115 79 45 9 -55 -49 78 -51 11 74 45 46 -56 -49 43 78 -27 46 1 -15 56 -117 83 83 83 -124 83 43 -110 83 11 64 -102 -40
>   100 45 44 -52 -51 -51 12 77 45 45 13 -115 44 -52 13 88 15 -34 116 -40
>   -68 -102 -127 -127 -127 17 0 28 31 43 78
>
> UNCOMPRESSED IN INFLATE FUNCTION
>
> ERROR

Comment: PC OS : Windows 7 (my machine)

Server OS : Windows 2008 Server R2 Standard SP1

JDK 1.6u23

Comment: Answer has been found by Norman Maurer

https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/487#issuecomment-7465563

Comment: byte[] bufferBytes = request.getContent().duplicate().array();
This does not pay attention of the readerIndex and writerIndex. It worked before as we just create a new array and copy the bytes over in <= 3.5.1.Final, but you should never depend on that. It would even not work if you would use direct buffers, so thats the other downside.

Comment: In newer versions of netty we share the backed array and so we safe memory copies and so are faster. So the correct way of get all readable bytes is:

byte[] bufferBytes = new byte[request.getContent().readableBytes()];
request.getContent().getBytes(request.getContent().readerIndex(), bufferBytes);
Hope this helps to explain it.